What would sunsets look like around different star types?
I have always wondered what a sunset would look like around different types of stars. I have tried to do some research into the types of light refraction, but I cannot find any answers anywhere, and many of the information I can gather is... Less than conclusive, to say the least.
In order to put this question to rest, and to provide any people with similar questions with an answer, I have come to consult the experts.
What would a sunset look like around various stars (Assuming, say, a blue star wouldn't strip away our atmosphere near-instantly)?
I would like to know the answers to an Orange (Class M), White (Class F or A), and radiant Blue (Class O). Once again, this assumes that all environmental conditions (Atmosphere, stellar position, etc.) remain identical, the planet will remain 50/50 with the cast light, and there will be no fallout from Sol turning into a blue supergiant. Please disregard any extinction-level events in your reply, as I have already adjusted everything (Orbits, environmental conditions, stellar positions, the radiation, ETC) to each star type for habitable conditions. I want to know how the sunset would look.

All stars are white light sources.

@JustAnotherUser I don't know that that question has much more merit, Rayleigh Scattering is pretty much independent of atmospheric chemistry and spectral adsorption lines are insignificant on the scale of Marque I Eyeball sensitivity.

@AlexP Yes but also regardless of their peak emission or surface temperature all stars actually emit white light in the visible spectrum, they show no visible difference to the human eye or to basic instrumentation, you need hyper-spectral instruments that can check on the stellar atmosphere's adsorption lines to tell stars apart if you set them all to the same visual magnitude.

@JustAnotherUser, Oh. I did not know that it is the atmosphere, and not the star. May you tell me more?

@Vesper I tried, but I don't think they like me very much. My question was deleted on the basis of it not being specific. And thus, I came here.

@JustAnotherUser Ah! I understand. So, perhaps, if the atmospheric pressure were 2 Bar and had a higher Oxygen content, then perhaps it would be a different hue? Do I understand you?

This might have been migrated too hastily. Consider this question on Worldbuilding that discusses atmospheric colors based on star color and atmospheric pressures, which might have gone a long way to answer your question (but that only means it might have been closed as a duplicate rather than migrated).

Maybe ask an artist about this question, because what sunset looks like for different stars is not what astronomers really care about.

@Polaris5744 Originally this was simply a question meant not for Astronomy, but instead for Xenobiology. Specifically, I wished to know what kinds of light a certain type of star would present, and therefore help me fuel my research into what sorts of adaptations the plants or plant-like flora would have with said stars.

Also, I am not an Astronomer.

Oh, so if you are talking about electromagnetic radiation, then you can google Planck's Law and Wien's Displacement law.

@Polaris5744... What a damn fool I am, why didn't I think of the radiation? Here I was, stuck on how different forms of refracted light would affect plants, and I did not even consider the idea of my star scouring all life with its wrath and radiance. Well, thank you.
